# What is the difference between ">" and "&>" in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, console

In bash we have 3 stream types:

- 0 (STDIN)
- 1 (STDOUT)
- 2 (STDERR)

So, while executing some program i can use these streams (e.g. i can redirect them from console to a file or smth like /dev/null, etc):

```
# only errors from STDERR will be shown, STDOUT will be moved to /dev/null
command > /dev/null
# only STDOUT will be shown, STDERR will be moved to /dev/null
command 2> /dev/null
```

I saw that some people write
`command &> /dev/null`

What is the difference between `>` and `&>` in bash?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> what is the difference between ">" and "&>" in bash?

It's a bashism that redirects both `stdout` and `stderr`. It can also be achieved with the more portable:

```
command > file 2>&1
```